# Error libnvidia-ml.so.1: cannot open shared object file raised when running docker image with gpu

Tags: docker, gpu

The error:

```
nvidia-container-cli: initialization error: load library 
failed: libnvidia-ml.so.1: cannot open shared object file: no 
such file or directory: unknown
```

I am trying to use nvidia/cuda image in docker hub to use GPU.
So I run the code below with --gpus all.

```
docker run -it --gpus all -v --name my-gpu nvidia/cuda:11.7.0-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu22.04
```

But this gives me error which is as below.

```
Unable to find image 'nvidia/cuda:11.7.0-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu22.04' locally

11.7.0-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu22.04: Pulling from nvidia/cuda
d19f32bd9e41: Already exists 
292e5e4dcc78: Already exists 
f027458ef473: Already exists 
ad9cd0a3350e: Already exists 
4c0e748dfb24: Already exists 
e40f2cbf6f5e: Pull complete 
3ac150f167fe: Pull complete 
dd80ebac36de: Pull complete 
fd2716719ab6: Pull complete 
e5ff1925518e: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:1055a2fa47b063336f578f390131efa4bb02fbfe095608481fd32b6fca9b8b32
Status: Downloaded newer image for nvidia/cuda:11.7.0-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu22.04
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error running hook #0: error running hook: exit status 1, stdout: , stderr: Auto-detected mode as 'legacy'
nvidia-container-cli: initialization error: load library failed: libnvidia-ml.so.1: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory: unknown.
ERRO[0465] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

But if I run the same code with sudo, it works completely fine.

```
sudo docker run -it --gpus all --name my-container-03  nvidia/cuda:11.7.0-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu22.04
```

How can I make it run without sudo? I must not run with sudo in my case now.

Comment: I wonder if it was already running. I'm trying now with sudo - but realize that there was a container already running using docker desktop ui.

Comment: I get the same error in windows11. I don;'t know how to run it in sudo mode? I tried opening the cmd in administrator mode, but not use.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

It was solved when I installed docker desktop.

Answer (score 2):

I had docker installed under `snap`. I removed it (`sudo snap remove --purge docker`) and reinstalled with `apt` and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, to use the nvidia runtime with the **nvidia-container-toolkit**, You have to use `sudo`.

Running it without `sudo` causes the `libnvidia-ml` error.

Here's what I did:

```bash
# BUILD IMAGE
sudo docker build -t upscayl:latest .

# RUN IMAGE WITH NVIDIA RUNTIME
sudo docker run --rm --runtime=nvidia --gpus all image:latest
```

Comment: I am using win11, and get this error. How do simulate a "sudo docker" run? Any ideas? I tried cmd in administrator mode but it did not help.

Comment: This is for Linux, sorry. I don't know if nvidia drivers even exist like that on Windows. It's just easier to use Docker on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I had the error described. In my case, what helped was to:

Uninstall everything (pre-existing CUDA + Nvidia drivers + docker). Then follow the steps to install (pre-installation, installation, post-installation):

https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html

That guide contains definitive instructions for uninstalling & installing (which I used and worked).